# Dynamically add resources to spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to make a videochat application with amazon web services in spring-boot. After the server download all files into /static/Download folder send as a ajax response an array of paths that should be set to video tag src . But when I'm trying to set a path to video src I recive "404 bad request" . I should download file somewhere else? Is spring boot able to load files that are added dynamically în static folder?